# Detecting Visual Studio Smart-tags events

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vsx, smart-tags

Is it possible to detect with VSX when any (or a particular) smart tag event is happening? I mean, every time we rename a variable, for example, a smart tag is available that allows us to change it through a form. I'd like to know if I can access that "text is changing" event.

I don't mean to have to check for myself if the text is being changed and such, I'd like to make use of VS event system (if there is one). I gave this example but I'd like to know the "general system" of how smart tags work with VSX.

Thanks